# mySQL - Selecting only records with consecutive occurrences

Tags: mysql

I am working on a table dealing with student records. Basically, I need to select only the records of students with at least 3 consecutive unregistered semesters.

Sample data:

```
StudentID|Unregistered|Semester
10000000 |Y           |1
10000000 |Y           |2
10000000 |Y           |6
10000001 |Y           |2
10000001 |Y           |8
10000001 |Y           |9
10000001 |Y           |10
10000002 |Y           |1
10000002 |Y           |2
10000002 |Y           |3
10000002 |Y           |10
```

I would want to only select the records from Student_ID 10000001 and 10000002.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: (and luckily, they're all unregistered)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql select where](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113055/mysql-select-where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is not very flexible but pretty simple. And it doesn't use session variables (which are evil):

```
select distinct r1.StudentID
from registrations r1
join registrations r2 
  on  r2.StudentID = r1.StudentID
  and r2.Semester  = r1.Semester + 1
join registrations r3
  on  r3.StudentID = r2.StudentID
  and r3.Semester  = r2.Semester + 1
where r1.Unregistered = 'Y'
  and r2.Unregistered = 'Y'
  and r3.Unregistered = 'Y';
```

A more flexible solution is:

```
set @num = 3;

select distinct r1.StudentID
from registrations r1
join registrations r2 
  on  r2.StudentID = r1.StudentID
  and r2.Semester  > r1.Semester
  and r2.Semester <= r1.Semester + @num - 1
where r1.Unregistered = 'Y'
  and r2.Unregistered = 'Y'
group by r1.StudentID, r1.Semester
having count(*) = @num - 1
```

That solution allows you to easily change the number of consecutive semesters.

http://rextester.com/HUUO33911

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you the count of consecutive semesters:

```
select s.id,
if(s.semester = @previousSem + 1 and @previousId = s.id, 
   @count := @count + 1, @count := 1) as count,
   @previousSem := s.semester as sem,
   @previousId := s.id as previousId
from sample s, (SELECT 
        @count := 1, 
        @previousSem := -1,
        @previousId := 0) a
order by s.id, s.semester
```

Now, you need to join this `query` with the main table (`self join`) and filter out the records with 3 or more counts, e.g.:

```
select s.id
from sample s join (select s.id,
if(s.semester = @previousSem + 1 and @previousId = s.id, 
   @count := @count + 1, @count := 1) as count,
   @previousSem := s.semester as sem,
   @previousId := s.id as previousId
from sample s, (SELECT 
        @count := 1, 
        @previousSem := -1,
        @previousId := 0) a
order by s.id, s.semester) s1
on s.id = s1.id
where s1.count >= 3
group by s.id;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/297fc/12/0)**.

P.S. removed `unregistered` column for brevity, you can add it in your actual query and add a `WHERE` condition (`WHERE registered = 'Y'`) in the inner query.